# Linq-to-sql EF4 - Generate list from

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following EF

```
Education {
long id,
string name,
}

User {
long id
string name
...
}

UserEducation
{
long userId,
long educationId,
long rank
}
```

I want to have a linq-to-sql call that will return results like:
UserName
Education as a list of education1, education2, education3, etc

I can get a result containing several education records for a user using

```
from u in users where u.userIsSomething.Equals(true)
join d in usereducation on u.id equals d.userid
join e in education on d.educationId equals e.Id
select new UserEd() {
  UserName = u.Name,
  Education =  <--- I end up with several unique education entries, I want to flatten into a list
```

So take records like

```
Fred   AA in Culinary Arts
Fred   BS in Food Science
Fred   MBA
```

to generate

Fred
AA in Culinary Arts, BS in Food Science, MBA

I realize I can simply loop over the records but I'd like to get it into one statement.

Haven't found similar question, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linq-to-sql or entity framework you should have navigation properties so your manual joins are redundant. If you don't have navigation properties you are using technology in the wrong way. Redefine your model to contain navigation properties and try this (untested):

```
var query = from u in context.Users where u.userIsSomething.Equals(true)
            select new UserEd {
                UserName = u.Name,
                Education = from ue in u.UserEducations
                            group ue by ue.Rank into grouped
                            select new RankedEd {
                                grouped.Key,
                                grouped.Select(g => g.Education.Name) 
                            }
            });
```